# django admin interface throwing csrf on image upload

Tags: python, django, django-admin, ckeditor, csrf

I am implementing blog in django and using django ckeditor , as Rich text field.
But problem arises when i upload image using inbuilt image uploader.It throws 403 csrf error.
I have googled intensively and found decorators solutions such as @csrf_exempt , but i dont know where to add them , since image uploading is integrated in ckeditor , which is being used in admin interface for model.

```
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField

class Post(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
text = RichTextField()
```

ckeditor config for setting.py is as fololw :

```
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = PROJECT_DIR +'/media/uploads'
```

Comment: do you use the last version of CKEDITOR ? because [the source code i digged](https://github.com/shaunsephton/django-ckeditor/blob/master/ckeditor/views.py#L110) uses csrf_expempt already

Comment: Yes i used the latest version , but was'nt able to use it. I switched to markdown now and I am lot more happy.